# How to remove a physical body in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I Added the coins on the track of user by creating a Sprite, which i kept in a Body. The problem is when the player collide with coin, the coin removed but it takes a jerk for nano second. I want the player to run smooth even when he collides with the coin.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what should happen in the first place? There are several possible solutions to this depending on what exactly you want to accomplish. What are the game mechanics, is the player collecting the coins?

Comment: Yes, Player runs and jump over different hurdles and collects  coin. the problem is when player collect coin, coin disappears but player takes a pause of nano seconds. I Think it may be due to box 2d. Have you any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, the problem is due to Box2D. Obviously, removing a body takes some time and causes some delay. If you don't plan to have a very large number of bodies you can just keep them the whole time, you can attach a sensor to the body. Sensor is a special kind of fixture that does not cause collisions with other bodies but you can find out whether the bodies are touching. This way you could keep the coins in their place and only remove the Sprite so that the coin will disappear without the overhead caused by removing a body.

See the Box2d manual here:
http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972

Another thing is collision filtering, although I am not certain whether the isTouching() method would return true if the collision bits are set up appropriately, so you'll have to try that. There is a nice tutorial here:
http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering